# Delete files from external and internal storage saved in a certain period of time

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I am developing an application and I would want to be able to delete the files saved on the internal and external device in a certain period of time (for example, files saved from DateTime1 from DateTime2).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clean your question. Try to ask specific problem you are facing in implementation.

Comment: i need to delete files from internal and external storage which saved in particular time period. i.e. ( saved files between 10 am to 8 pm )

Comment: Could you please post some more information related to what you tried to do? Some code snippets or something.

Comment: i have no idea that how we can delete files from storage , i found code to delete directories when uninstall app, but i dont want to uninstall app.

Comment: You will have to try to do some more research before asking for help. You cannot expect the community to do your research for you. I am certain that it's not that hard to find some examples of removing files from internal/external storage.

Comment: my main aim is to disable USB drive that user cant theft any data but that is not possible so i am trying to found other ways to delete files for stipulated time from my background service. i understand nobody will give ready source for this , but atleast anybody have idea, they will share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i have no idea that how we can delete files from storage

Use standard Java I/O. To delete a `File` (whether it is pointing to a file or an empty directory), call [`delete()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29). Note that for external storage you will need to hold the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.